# Putty double tunnel

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, tunneling

Currently I have the following problem: I can connect to Server B via ssh only if I connect to Server A (via ssh), create socks proxy with putty, and use it in order to connect to server B.

So connection is **MyPC** -> **Server A** -> **Server B**. What I need is to be able to call from **Server B localhost:xx** and forward it to **MyPc:xx**

With single tunnel it can be done via Putty by simply adding rule `R7869 localhost:7869` (and it's working for **Server A** which connection is being made directly), however if I'm trying to do the same on **Server B** (which is proxyfied) it's not working.

Any ideas?

***EDIT:*** I have found solution to this problem. Instead of creating new network connection with putty to server B, I need to call `ssh -R 7869:localhost:7869 root@ServerB` from Server A.

Comment: There is a good solution here http://serverfault.com/questions/340865/ssh-tunnel-over-multi-hops-using-putty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What i need is to be able to call from server B localhost:xx and forward it to MyPc:xx"

First session to server_A: a.example.com:22

```
 L22000 b.example.com:22
```

Second session to server_B (via tunnel from first session): localhost:22000

```
 L8080 localhost:8080
```

The end effect is MyPC:8080 <-> b.example.com:8080